# Get the maximum values of column B per each distinct value of column A sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this table:

[image]

I am trying to pull all records from this table for the max value in the DIST_NO column for every distinct ID in the left most column, but I still want to pull every record for each ID in which there are different Product_ID's as well.

I tried partitioning and using row_number, but I am having trouble at the moment.

Here are my desired results:

[image: Desired Results]

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
select *
from
    (SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DIST_NO DESC) RN
    FROM Table) V
WHERE RN<=3
```

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data and desired results *as text* in the question.

Comment: I cant add the sample data into my questions as I need higher reputation points, but for the desired result I would like to see

Answer (score 1):

you want the `max(DIST_NO)` for each `ID, product_ID`?
If so, you can:

```
SELECT
ID, product_ID, max(DIST_NO)
from table
group by ID, product_ID
```

---

If you want the detail rows related to the max row, you just need to join it back to your table:

```
Select
    t.ID, max_dist_no, TRANSaction_ID     , LINE_NO     , PRODUCT_ID
from
table t inner join
(SELECT
    ID, max(DIST_NO) as max_dist_no
    from table
    group by ID) mx on
t.ID = mx.ID and
t.DIST_NO = max_DIST_NO
```

Comment: Will not return the desired result.

Comment: thanks for adding the desired result to your question.

Comment: Thanks Beth for the response, can you have both 'max_dist_no' in the original query and the sub query. I am getting an error when using this form for my query.

Comment: @TristanS. not sure what error you're getting, but the ID field needs to be aliased

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT MT.ID
     , MT.DIST_NO
     , MT.TRANS_ID
     , MT.LINE_NO
     , MT.PRODUCT_ID
  FROM MYTABLE MT 
      INNER JOIN (
           SELECT T.ID, MAX(T.DIST_NO) as DIST_NO FROM MYTABLE T
           GROUP BY T.ID
      ) MAX_MT ON MT.Id = MAX_MT.ID AND MT.DIST_NO = MAX_MT.DIST_NO
```

The sub query returns each combination of ID and `Max` value of DIST_NO:

```
 SELECT T.ID, MAX(T.DIST_NO) as DIST_NO FROM MYTABLE T
           GROUP BY T.ID
```

Joining this back to your original table will basically filter your original data-set by only these combinations of values.

Comment: And I prefer the current derived table version. Also more portable, since not all dbms products support cte's.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT t.*
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DIST_NO DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Table t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This is almost a literal translation of your request:

> I am trying to pull all records from this table for the max value in
>   the DIST_NO column for every distinct ID in the left most column.

Comment: Will this still return multiple records for a distinct ID if there are multiple product ID's?

Comment: @TristanS. . .. Yes, it will.  That is the difference between `row_number()` and the rank functions.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on PostgreSQL:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT id, product_id, MAX(dist_no) AS dist_no 
    FROM test
    GROUP BY 1,2)
SELECT t1.id, t1.dist_no, t2.trans_id, t2.line_no, t1.product_id
FROM test t2, t1
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.product_id=t2.product_id AND t1.dist_no=t2.dist_no
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this one :). (But is your result correct? I think there is little mistake in TRANS_ID...)

```
DECLARE @ExampleTable TABLE 
        (ID INT,
         DIST_NO INT,
         TRANS_ID INT,
         LINE_NO INT,
         PRODUCT_ID INT)

INSERT INTO @ExampleTable
        ( ID, DIST_NO, TRANS_ID,LINE_NO, PRODUCT_ID )
VALUES  ( 102657,  1,  1105365,  1,  109119   ),
        ( 102657,  1,  1105366,  2,  109114   ),
        ( 102657,  2,  1105365,  1,  109119   ),
        ( 102657,  2,  1105366,  2,  109114   ),
        ( 104371,  1,  1190538,  1,  110981   ),
        ( 104371,  2,  1190538,  1,  110981   )


;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, LINE_NO
                FROM @ExampleTable)

SELECT a.ID, 
       x.DIST_NO, 
       x.TRANS_ID, 
       x.LINE_NO, 
       x.PRODUCT_ID
FROM CTE a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
               FROM @ExampleTable f 
             WHERE a.ID = f.ID AND 
                   a.LINE_NO = f. LINE_NO 
             ORDER BY DIST_NO DESC) x
```